# Linq query with Take() to Mysql does not add limit to actual query

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using net core 2.2 with Pomelo EntityFramework with MySql database.

The following code:

```
return context.SomeTable
        .OrderByDescending(item => item.ExpiredTime)
        .Where(item => item.FinishedTime.HasValue
            && item.ExpiredTime.HasValue
            && item.ExpiredTime.Value < DateTime.UtcNow
            && item.IsArchive.GetValueOrDefault(false) == false/* is null or false*/)
        .Take(500)
        .Select(i=>new ItemWrapper(i))
        .ToArray();
```

Returns the following MySql:

```
SELECT `item`.`Id`, `item`.`ExpiredTime`, `item`.`FinishedTime`, 
`item`.`IsArchive`
FROM `SomeTable` AS `item`
WHERE (`item`.`FinishedTime` IS NOT NULL AND `item`.`ExpiredTime` IS NOT 
NULL) AND (`item`.`ExpiredTime` < UTC_TIMESTAMP())
ORDER BY `item`.`ExpiredTime` DESC
```

It seems like the `Take(500)` is not being reflected in the query.

I expect to see `limit = 500` in the sql query.
Edit 1:
I am using `Select(i=>new ItemWrapper(i)` to create a new class for the result object, it seems to be the root of the issue.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that's because you are calling `item.IsArchive.GetValueOrDefault(false) == false`. EF cannot translate this function to SQL so it materializes everything before it and then try to continue to apply the rest to the data retrieved from SQL server. Try to remove this condition or rewrite it. Usually EF.Core shows warnings in the log before it runs the actual query.

Comment: You should expect limit 0, 500 instead of limit = 500 in MySQL.

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich your answer resolves the issue

Comment: @ErezBenHarush converted my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are calling `item.IsArchive.GetValueOrDefault(false) == false` in `Where` clause. EF.Core cannot translate this method to SQL so it materializes all the items first and then tries to apply the rest to the data retrieved from SQL server. Try to remove this condition or rewrite it. BTW, usually EF.Core shows warnings for these kind of issues in the log.